# Replacement stickers

Tags: stickers

Can I purchase a sheet of stickers for 4643 Power Boat Transporter?  My son got the item as a gift and a friend of his put the stickers on wrong and he is very upset about it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the set is still being produced, you can call Lego Customer Service at 1-800-835-4386, and they will most likely be able to help you.

Failing that, the BrickLink website is a popular place to buy replacement parts. Here's the link for the sticker sheet:
http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemID=102237

It looks like there are a handful of sellers in the US selling the stickers for $1-$2. Registration on the site is easy, and most of the sellers accept PayPal.